Why does changing the system language cause my Android NativeActivity to crash?
My game is based on NativeActivity and crashes for some reason when the user changes the phone language while the game is running. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?
My app consists of two activities - a Launch activity that provides user configuration data for the game and the Game activity in which the game runs. The Launcher always runs first when the app is opened from scratch. If the Game activity is backgrounded normally and switched back to later it will display the game without going through the launch activity.
So the behavior I'm seeing is as follows.

User taps on game icon
Launch activity displays and lets user config some things if desired
Launch activity launches Game activity
Switch to System Settings and change language
Switch back to game
Game activity exits
Launch activity reappears

The behavior I expect to see is at step 6 the game should resume as normal. But it appears the game activity is getting an APP_CMD_DESTROY. Is that expected behavior for Android? My game activity is Vulkan based and doesn't need to be destroyed and re-created. And re-creation causes all graphics resources to reload and that can take 30-60 seconds - an undesirable user experience.
Is there a way to ignore or opt out of such activity re-creations?

Changing the language is a configuration change.  Configuration changes recreate the activity.  onConfigurationChange isn't called either because it's recreated instead (from the docs: "Note that this will only be called if you have selected configurations you would like to handle with the R.attr.configChanges attribute in your manifest.") or because you have a typo (it's onConfigurationChanged).  I have no idea why it's crashing, but you likely aren't handling Activity recreation correctly.

please provide more info on this, you can check the Logcat to see what went wrong, but in general, when you change language, everything is recreated again (with a new configuration) so it's likely that your app is not working properly with the selected language, please update the question with more contexed description hope it helped

I'm not sure what more to add. LogCat doesn't contain anything that seems useful. Is there something specific I should be looking for? Also note that I've found changing the system font to Bold then switching back to my game causes the same problem. And in that case I'm getting an APP_CMD_DESTROY for some reason. What do you mean when you say "everything is recreated"? Does it destroy my current activity and reload the app from scratch? If so then perhaps the behavior I'm seeing is expected?

Yes it was a typo on the callback. I've fixed that. I don't think my NativeActivity is re-creatable. I have a Launcher activity that happens first and provides configuration data for the Game activity to launch. I'll update my question to show that.
